# Struggling to make JNI call c++ dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, java-native-interface

My code is as follows

Java file

```
//SystemInformation.java
package test;

public class SystemInformation {

    static{
        try{
            System.loadLibrary("SysInfo");
        }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
            System.out.println ("native lib '" + "SystemInformation" + "' not found in 'java.library.path': "
            + System.getProperty ("java.library.path"));

            throw e; // re-throw
        }
    }

    public native static int getDouble(int n);
    public int GetDouble(int n){
        return getDouble(n);
    }

}
```

C++ code to create DLL

```
//SysInfo.cpp
#include "jni.h"






   JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test_SystemInformation_getDouble
(JNIEnv *env, jclass jcls, jint n) {
    return n * 2;

}
```

Header generated by Javah.exe

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class test_SystemInformation */

#ifndef _Included_test_SystemInformation
#define _Included_test_SystemInformation
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     test_SystemInformation
 * Method:    getDouble
 * Signature: (I)I
 */
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_test_SystemInformation_getDouble
  (JNIEnv *, jclass, jint);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

I am not getting exception when I call loadLibrary("SysInfo")

When I try to call GetDouble function from main then it throws error message in console

```
//Main.java
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SystemInformation sInfo = new SystemInformation();
        long l = sInfo.GetDouble(4);
        System.out.println("Double Value = " + l);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Error I am getting is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: test.SystemInformation.getDouble(I)I
    at test.SystemInformation.getDouble(Native Method)
    at test.SystemInformation.GetDouble(SystemInformation.java:18)
    at test.Main.main(Main.java:6)
```

I tried lots of options but none of them working

1. My machine if 64 but
2. Java version is also 64 bit
3. I am creating 64 bit version if dll in visual studio
4. I tried /MTd /MDd flags while creating dll but non of them working
5. DLL is getting loaded properly as I am not getting exception when System.loadLibrary("SysInfo"); is called
6. Here is signature of function

   ?Java_test_SystemInformation_getDouble@@YAJPEAUJNIEnv_@@PEAV_jclass@@J@Z

Any suggestions will really be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe as simple as your dll-file missing in searched paths ?

Comment: As I have mentioned before I am not getting exception when I call System.loadLibrary("SysInfo");, so it means dll is loaded properly.

Comment: … and there are only a singel correct dll-file around ? (Sorry for asking somewhat fundamental things but this is where I usually trip myself)

Comment: Yes I copied one dll into Java workspace folder

Comment: More guesses: your signature at pt 6. looks a lot like c++ namemangling, perhaps the extern "C" wrap is for some reason not in effect ? I see no include in SysInfo.cpp.

Comment: Thansks @jojje adding header file to SysInfo.cpp worked